How to Create a Halftone Dot Effect in Blender Similar to This Reference Image?
Hello Blender Community,
I'm trying to create a halftone dot effect in Blender similar to the one shown in the reference image attached. The goal is to have a series of dots that appear uniformly shaded, forming a pattern.
Here are the specific challenges I'm facing:

Ensuring each dot has a consistent shading value without being partially covered by different values.
Achieving the overall look and feel of the pattern seen in the image.

What I have tried so far:

Applying a halftone texture to my grid of points.
Adjusting UV mapping and shading settings.

I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to achieve this effect in Blender. Specifically, I'm looking for advice on:

The best way to create and apply a halftone texture.
Ensuring uniform shading for each dot.
Any tips on node setups or modifiers that might help.

Thank you in advance for your help!
Reference image

My Test

My Shading node setup

My Geometry ode setup


FYI, your reference image doesn't match the generally agreed on definition of "halftone". Halftone is (usually in print) the use of dots of varied sizes to give the appearance of shading. Not trying to nit-pick, but people will find this from a web search, and it might not be what they're looking for. See: Halftone material Your reference image is more akin to an LED dot matrix display. See: Dot matrix material The answer Markus von Broady contributed for GeoNodes is also great. ;-)



Achieving the overall look and feel of the pattern seen in the image.


I would describe it as columns of circles, with semi-random brightness. The semi-randomness is resembling Perlin noise in the sense that neighbors tend to have similar values. Neighbors similarity is limited within each column, however; there is no horizontal similarity.
You can achieve that with a Noise Texture, multiplying the $x$ coordinate by a lot, so that while each column has the same $x$ coordinate, neighboring columns have its coords spread out to remove resemblance between columns. The rest is I think obvious: instance circles/spheres, store the attribute for shader, I decided to also resign from displaying the darkest spheres:

The shader just uses the stored attribute to control the strength of bloom:

Bloom settings; you already made the world a dark place:
 
Result:



Fantastic! This is exactly what I need. Thank you so much !
